# Force an async function to finish before next task

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm using a python API wrapper with `async` functions.  I need to call the API several times and would like to override the `async` functionality by waiting for each task to complete before moving on to the next iteration.

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for count in range(5):
    loop.create_task(main(count)) # Need this line to complete before next iteration
    time.sleep(60) # Hacky solution
```

Currently I'm just sleeping until I can assume `main()` is complete.  How can I ensure main() never runs concurrently with itself?

Answer (score 2):

To wait for the task to finish, use `await`. This requires an async function, which you can run using `asyncio.run`:

```
async def x():
    for count in range(5):
        await main(count)

asyncio.run(x())
```

If you want to do the same from top-level code, just call `run_until_complete` as many times as needed:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for count in range(5):
    loop.run_until_complete(main(count))
```

Comment: When I do run_until_complete I get `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`, which I can fix by also using `nest_asyncio`, but I am curious if there's a native way to do it.

Comment: @Jeremy414 How are you running your code, as a script or in a console?